# Proving commutator subgroup is normal

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Part of Aluffi II.7.11 suggests proving this claim.

It is actually quite straightforward (especially after some earlier problems in the book): I've managed to prove it by noticing that for arbitrary $a, b, g$: $$g aba^{-1} b^{-1} g^{-1} = (gag^{-1})(gbg^{-1})(gag^{-1})^{-1}(gbg^{-1})^{-1}$$ which is in $[G, G]$, thus it's trivial to show that for arbitrary $n \in [G, G]$ the element $gng^{-1}$ is also in $[G, G]$ by interspersing it with some number of $g^{-1}g$'s.

My question, though, is a bit different (and that's what's different from all other questions about normality of commutators that MSE suggests as similar). Aluffi gives a hint that $g \cdot aba^{-1}b^{-1} \cdot g^{-1} = \gamma_g(aba^{-1}b^{-1})$, where $\gamma_g : a \mapsto gag^{-1}$ is an inner automorphism on $G$ defined by the element $g$. I don't think I've followed this hint and thus I haven't built a "more categorical" proof that Aluffi might have expected here. So, is there a way to prove the claim using this hint?

Comment: I think you have followed the hint.

Comment: Aluffi's hint is, as explained in Berci's answer, just a different way of organizing your calculation. But this reorganization has real value, because it shows that the commutator subgroup is invariant under all automorphisms of $G$, not just the inner ones. (In other words, it shows that the commutator subgroup is a characteristic subgroup, which is a stronger property than normality.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implicitly did follow the hint:

The point is that $\gamma_g$ is an inner *automorphism*, implying it's a group homomorphism, so that
$$\gamma_g(xy) =\gamma_g(x)\gamma_g(y)$$
which was the crucial part in your proof, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Andreas Blass in his comment has the key to the "more categorical" approach.

The commutator can be viewed as a *functor* on the category of groups. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) is good on this.

It follows that the commutator subgroup is a *fully characteristic subgroup*,(ie, it is stable under any endomorphism).

Thus it is automatically a normal subgroup.  This is because the normality condition can be phrased as invariance under inner automorphisms.

Comment: I believe the usual terminology is “fully invariant”, rather than “fully characteristic”; at least, that’s the one I normally encounter. (In fact, the commutator subgroup is even more than fully invariant: it is verbal, which is what yields the functoriality)